# New to Access 2013 - Would like to create a dynamic search form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to Access 2013 and would like to create a form that allows users to interactively enter search parameters and see the results listed on the same form as multiple items or a data sheet.

This would work like a search on a web page:

Users will enter search criteria and click a search button.  A data grid will display the results.  Each time the user re-enters the search criteria, the data grid will be reloaded with the query results.  It is important that the user not be required to launch one form to enter the criteria and see the results on another form.  All should be done on the same form.

My questions are:

1. If I use VBA to handle the click event and perform the query, is it possible to programmatically set the control source of a data sheet or multiple items to the new query results?

Answer (score 1):

The method that I used to create a dynamic search form is:

1. Create an Access Form to prompt for search paramaters.  Mine consisted of two text boxes with format set to general date. (I want to list all rows between a start and end date), an unbound list box for the results and a command button to execute the search.
2. Create an Access Query that uses a Criteria setting that references the starting and ending text boxes on the search form.  The field name I want to use is named EventDate.  In the QBE, I set the Criteria entry for the EventDate field to:

Between [Forms]![frmSimpleSearch]![txtStartDate] And [Forms]![frmSimpleSearch]![txtEndingEventDate]

1. For the Click event of the Search button, I use the following code:

   Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

   ' Search for all events between the start and end date
     lstResults.RowSource = "qryEventsInDateRange"
     lstResults.Requery

   End Sub